# Mockito thenReturn returning different values

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

So I have test like this:

```
public class TimesheetServiceTest {
    @Mock
    Repository repository;
    @Mock
    ServiceToMockResult serviceToMockResult;
    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceToTest serviceToTest = new ServiceToTestImpl();

    @Test
    public void testLongResult() {
        when(serviceToMockResult.getResult(any(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(20L); //it's supposed to always return 20L
        //8 items length result list
        List<Long> results = this.serviceToTest.getResults();
       //some more testing after ....
    }
}
```

As you can see the serviceToMock.getResult() method gets called inside of the ServiceToTest. So after doing this I get the 8 results I expect but some of them are value 0, and I also noticed that it's always position 5 and 7 in list. It's worth noticing that when I call serviceToMock.getResult() directly in test without passing through the other class, I get the expected result.

**Expected Result**

20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20

**Actual Result**

20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 0, 20, 0

Comment: I'm not sure you have to instanciate ServiceToTest, that can lead to a conflict with mockito. It should be @InjectMocks
    private ServiceToTest serviceToTest;

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD yes I do because as you can see ServiceToTest is an interface, the implementation I want it's ServiceToTestImpl.

Comment: @InjectMocks private ServiceToTestImpl serviceToTest; my bad

Comment: okay thank you but I still have the same problem with thenReturn method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument matcher `any(String.class)` matches any String, excluding nulls.

See [ArgumentMatchers.any](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.6.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-) documentation:

> `public static <T> T any(Class<T> type)`
>
> Matches any object of given type, excluding nulls.

Most likely you are calling serviceToMockResult.getResult() with a null argument.
As such a call is not stubbed, default value for the return type is returned (which is `0` for `long`)

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While injecting mocks to a bean/service instead of creating it, let it create by mocks. Also init Mockito anntotation before processing.

Example:

```
public class TimesheetServiceTest {
    @Mock
    Repository repository;
    @Mock
    ServiceToMockResult serviceToMockResult;

    // let mockito create the service. 
    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceToTest serviceToTest;

    @Test
    public void testLongResult() {
        // Init mocks
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        when(serviceToMockResult.getResult(any(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(20L);
        // This should work fine.

    }
}
```